# I am looking for a framework for QR-Style Codes

Tags: framework, qr-code

I have a customer request to create a custom qr-style code like Spotify, FB Messenger or Instagram. They all have their custom codes which they have developed. I am searching for what kind of data representation a "QR" code is considered along with any frameworks, tutorials, blog or otherwise to crate such an element. Code language is not a problem, I just need to understand what the subject is or called so that I can find more information.